# Why not have one login to all stack subdomains?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, cookies, auto-login

Hello guys,

Whenever i visit a new stack subdomain website, i have to re-register with my google open id. Why not have one login for all sites, that way it wouldn't have to keep re-asking me for my info for a new stack overflow website. Just a suggestion.

Thanks for all the help on all stack subdomains everybody.

Comment: They kinda have one, but it's buggy.  It will sometimes sign you in, and sometimes not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They have one: http://stackauth.com

Except not everyone want to be member of all site, so whenever there's a new site, you have to subscribe again, but you will have one account, you can find yours [here](https://stackexchange.com/users/7903aa0d-678f-4fb3-a0bd-e228d47d2cad).

But then, once you're subscribed, you'll only have to log onto one site, and the other one will log you automagically.

Comment: "not everyone want to be member of all site".  That shouldn't be even be a question.  You're either a member of stackexchange or not.  You either participate in a subdomain or don't.  I was going to participate in english.se.com but I need to enter my name, email and password again?  Or go to a mysterious stackauth.com that I never would have known about except for your post?  Ridiculous!

Comment: I just clicked on that link and it took me to nowhere helpful.